# let A be a $2\times 2$ matrix . Then the smallest number $n\in \mathbb N$ such that $A^n=I$ is

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, computability

let A be a $2\times 2$ matrix $\begin{pmatrix} \sin \frac \pi {18} & -\sin \frac {4\pi} {9}\\
\sin \frac {4\pi} {9}&\sin \frac \pi {18}\end{pmatrix}$. Then the smallest number $n\in \mathbb N$ such that $A^n=I$ is

> > (a). 3
> >
> > (b). 9
> >
> > (c). 18
> >
> > (d). 27

**My work**

I checked for the order for 3. But, I could know that I am wrong in this way. And I tried to find that "Is it nth roots of some complex numbers" but in that way also I could not achieve. How can I proceed?

If I give this matrix what is the answer
$$\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\
0& \sin \frac \pi {18} & -\sin \frac {4\pi} {9}\\
0&\sin \frac {4\pi} {9}&\sin \frac \pi {18}\end{pmatrix}$$

Answer (score 6):

Using the identity

$$\sin x=\cos\left(x-\frac\pi2\right)$$
we see that the given matrix is a matrix of rotation of angle $\frac{4\pi }{9}$ hence the answer is $9$.

Comment: It is rotation matrix .But can you please explain how you have got 9

Comment: The matrix $A^n$ is also a rotation matrix with angle $ \frac{4n\pi}{9}$ so what's the value of $n$ to get a multiple of $2\pi$.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a hint (assuming you are indeed missing a minus sign): $\sin \frac{\pi}{18} = \cos \frac{4\pi}{9}$.